# Mysql workbench results grid has extra panel with hast symbol next to it, how can I remove it?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm using mysql workbench on Ubuntu, and I seem to have hit a wrong key somewhere along the way, now I have an extra panel on my results grid blocking up my small screen.
[image: Mysql workbench screenshot]

Does anybody know how to hide this panel??

Comment: Does it go back to normal once you restart the software?

Comment: What platform (including version) is that and which version of WB do you use here?